# Getting different result from an mvc action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a business layer that has some `IEnumerable` methods.  I used those methods in my controller and get result after make methods result to `.ToList()`.

Now there is a new requirement. I have to filter action result data per user access.  When users call an action method, only one business layer method called, but I need different result per user. For example: user A can load all data but user B only access 10 rows data according by his permission.

Code:

**BL:**

```
public IEnumerable<Card> GetCardList(int Id)
{
    return unitOfWork.GetCardList(Id);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
//...   
CardBl.GetCardList(id).ToList();
//...
```

I tried to filter data in a CustomActionFilter class by overriding `OnActionExecuting` or `OnResultExecuting` methods, but I'm confused!

Actually I want to make this kind of filtering automate by attributes instead of adding `where` clause for every method.

I would appreciate if anyone suggest a solution.

**Update:**
My Model:

```
public class CardModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public string CardDescription { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }

}
```

`CityId` is the property that I have to filter data based on.

Comment: You need a `.Where()` clause to filter the result. You have not indicated what property you want to filter the results on.

Comment: I use claim base identity, then I have users claim collections on the fly. City claim is my key to filter result. I want to filter result base on. StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to show your model and indicate what property you want to filter the results on

Comment: But how does that relate in anyway to the user and their permissions? Besides that's not the model in your `GetCardList()` method returns which is `Test`, not `LineModels`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, i changed my model name before post my question because of some privacy issues. I'll modify it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111289/discussion-between-alex-and-stephen-muecke).